# Using prometheus.io client in sinatra application

Tags: ruby, sinatra, prometheus

I have a Sinatra application and I want to deploy [prometheus.io](https://github.com/prometheus/client_ruby) client there. The Readme shows only how to deploy it using Rack. What is the most feasible way to deploy the client there?

Answer (score 0):

Rack is an interface, it is not a web server.

Sinatra and Ruby on Rails are Rack applications.

So all options available for Rack apply here. For example you could deploy it with Nginx.